# Dynamically set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER in curl php

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I have an application that uses curl for making API requests. Since the APIs works in https I have to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)` in my localhost. I would like to set this value dynamically by checking whether the ssl enabled. I have seen php openssl check using extension_loaded() function. But I am not sure it is the right way.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: If ssl is not enabled how would changing CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER do anything? If you can't do requests to https urls I don't see how changing a property that only effects if you do requests to https urls

Comment: @WizKid setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false is the only way to request https url from localhost.

Comment: Yes, and you need to have ssl enabled to do that request. If ssl is not enabled that option doesn't do anything.